# how do nested if statements and the && (and) operator differ inside this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects, and-operator

There's similar questions on here, but I couldn't find one related to this. Here's my question:

These two functions output different results. I was under the impression that the && operator essentially worked the same as a nested if statement. There is obviously a misunderstanding/logic mistake on my end about how the && operator works. I believe it has something to do with being in the loop and trying to read the conditions at the same time or something similar, but if anyone could elaborate on what's happening it would be appreciated. What is going on with the && operator in the second function and why is it outputting the property as not found?

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    }
];

function lookUp(arr, firstName, prop){
  for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){
    if (arr[x].firstName === firstName) 
      if (arr[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
        return arr[x][prop];
      else 
        return "No such property";
  }
}

lookUp(contacts, "Kristian", "likes")
// ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]

function lookUp(arr, firstName, prop){
  for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++){
    if (arr[x].firstName === firstName && arr[x].hasOwnProperty(prop))  
      return arr[x][prop];
    else 
        return "No such property";
  }
}

lookUp(contacts, "Kristian", "likes")
// "No such property"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct function could look like the following:

```
function lookUp(arr, firstName, prop) {
    for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
        if (arr[x].firstName === firstName && arr[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
            return arr[x][prop];
    }
    return "No such property";
}
```

### Explanation

Your loop will just have one iteration because when the first `if` is true it will `return arr[x][prop]` or if it is false it will `return "No such property"`

A `return` jumps *allways* out of a function and that is the reason why the loop stops

Instead of the "correct" solution will iterate through all array elements and if there isn't the provided name it will return with the `"No such property"`

Comment: It was the else statement. Also, I put in the wrong slice of code on accident, there was another return that was needed, but I can figure it out. That else statement is what was doing it. Need to remember not to bunch up if/&& and else statements or to be careful doing so in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second function is not equivalent to first one because inner if has else condition.

`AND` operator executes subsequent conditions only if it will get true.

For example:
 if condition is X == Y && Y == Z then Y == Z will executed only if X == Y

In your first case add one else for Condition 1, It will look like:

```
 if Condition1 {

       if condition2

         console.log("1");

      else

            console.log("2");
    }
    else 

        console.log("3");

    Second Case

     If Condition1 && Condition2
       console.log("1");
     else
       console.log("2 and 3");  // all the case of 2 and 3 come here
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working 100%

```
function lookUp(arr, firstName, prop){
    var lock;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if((arr[i].firstName == firstName) && (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)))
        {
            lock = arr[i][prop];
            break;
        }else{
            lock = "No such property";
        }
    }
    return lock;
}
```

Comment: Instead of stating "this is working 100%", it would be more useful if you would explain why your code solves the problem. Leave it to the OP to decide whether this code works for them.